# Nodejs Container Cant Access to Mysql Container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I create a app that uses mysql database but When I Dockerize My Services I cant Access to my containers from each other even i create a same network and put my service name in my database config
here is my docker compose and database config

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    container_name: mydb
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345678
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=something
      - MYSQL_USER=something
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345678
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    network_mode: "host"
  nodeserver:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: ./app
    network_mode: "host" 
volumes:
  db:
```

```
# pull the Node.js Docker image
FROM node:alpine

# create the directory inside the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy the package.json files from local machine to the workdir in container
COPY package*.json ./

# run npm install in our local machine
RUN npm install

# copy the generated modules and all other files to the container
COPY . .

# our app is running on port 5000 within the container, so need to expose it
EXPOSE 5000
# the command that starts our app
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

```
erver_1  | ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
nodeserver_1  |     at ConnectionManager.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:92:17)        
nodeserver_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
nodeserver_1  |     at async ConnectionManager._connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:216:24)
nodeserver_1  |     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
nodeserver_1  |     at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)
nodeserver_1  |     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/sequelize.js:303:26
nodeserver_1  |     at async MySQLQueryInterface.createTable (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:94:12)
nodeserver_1  |     at async Function.sync (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/model.js:913:5)
nodeserver_1  |     at async Sequelize.sync (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/dist/lib/sequelize.js:377:9)
nodeserver_1  |     at async initialize (/usr/src/app/_helpers/db.js:36:5) {
nodeserver_1  |   parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
nodeserver_1  |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
nodeserver_1  |     errno: -111,
nodeserver_1  |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
nodeserver_1  |     syscall: 'connect',
nodeserver_1  |     address: '127.0.0.1',
nodeserver_1  |     port: 3306,
nodeserver_1  |     fatal: true
nodeserver_1  |   },
nodeserver_1  |   original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
nodeserver_1  |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
nodeserver_1  |     errno: -111,
nodeserver_1  |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
nodeserver_1  |     syscall: 'connect',
nodeserver_1  |     address: '127.0.0.1',
nodeserver_1  |     port: 3306,
nodeserver_1  |     fatal: true
nodeserver_1  |   }
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

after run my projects with docker-compose up
i got this error
[image]

Comment: The address in the error message (127.0.0.1) indicates that it thinks the database host is `localhost` and not `mydb` as your config says. Try rebuilding your images and run again.

Comment: I do "docker-compose build" and after I do "docker-compose up" now ! but nothing changed !

Comment: Do you have `.env` file in same dir of `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: @Gupta no i dont have .env file i pass my envs directly into docker compose

Comment: You seem to have attached several image files to the question, but not your actual source code.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the image files with the text of your `docker-compose.yml` and other artifacts?

Comment: @DavidMaze excuse me sir , i attached my codes !

Comment: network_mode: "host"  with this everthing goes well but i checked from other and they said it cause an issue to our app and i prefer not to use this approch @Gupta

Comment: You should use a service name in docker network. Inside docker network DB is on host db. Then in yours config should have: 
"host": "db"

Comment: Can you please verify that in `initialize()` the value of `host` is `mydb`? I suspect it to be undefined.

Comment: @AliTou I checked it , its pass a value of "mydb" and everything ok , with normal yarn start i can connect to mysql on port 3306 but when I run two container , they cant talk to each others

Comment: Aha I just saw that you used host network. Can you also verify that MySQL is still running? If so, the initialization of MySQL is the problem. You're connecting to it before it becomes running, and a `wait-for-it` would be necessary to wait until MySQL is accepting connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by not providing the hostname into the Sequelize options and it defaults to localhost if you don't. You need to do something like the following:

```
new Sequelize(database, user, password, { dialect: 'mysql', host })
```

Reference (see Option #3): https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#connecting-to-a-database

Comment: thanks my dude , I waste my 3 days , it works for me !

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked for me.  I added the "host" entry in the <sequelize>.yaml file.

Content of my <sequelize.yaml> file: 

dbname: <abc123>
username: <abc123>
password: <abc123>
maxPasswordHistory: 6
#forcesync: true
params:
  dialect: postgres
  host: <abc123>                    <<<<<this was the problem. 
  logging: false
```